# Java Method Stubs

Tags: java

This is what I have to do:

Define stubs for the methods called by the below main(). Each stub should print "FIXME: Finish methodName()" followed by a newline, and should return -1.

Example output:

```
FIXME: Finish getUserNum()

FIXME: Finish getUserNum()

FIXME: Finish computeAvg()

Avg: -1
```

This is the code that I have:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MthdStubsStatistics {

    public static int methodName (int userNum1, int userNum2, int computerAvg) {
        System.out.println("FIXME: Finish getUserNum()");
        System.out.println("FIXME: Finish getUserNum()");
        System.out.println("FIXME: Finish computerAvg()");
        System.out.println("Avg: -1");

        return 0;

    }

    public static void main() {
        int userNum1 = 0;
        int userNum2 = 0;
        int avgResult = 0;

        userNum1 = getUserNum();
        userNum2 = getUserNum();

        avgResult = computeAvg(userNum1, userNum2);

        System.out.println("Avg: " + avgResult);

        return;
    }
}
```

I thought I understood method stubs, but I feel like I am making a very stupid and simple mistake? I can only edit the public static int methodName section of the code.

Comment: *"I can only edit the public static int methodName section of the code."* - I doubt that is true.  Read the instructions again.  If that is really what they say, then ask the person who wrote the instructions what they actually meant.

Comment: I imagine the directions say "only edit the public static int methodName", which should be interpreted as do not edit the main method, but instead you can only edit methods you are defining. "methodName" in the directions seems like a placeholder to describe both "getUserNum" and "computeAvg".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A method stub in this sense is a method with no real substance, i.e. it's not doing what it is intended to do. Your `getUserNum()` method should return a user's unique ID, but instead you're defining a stub that simply returns `-1` on every invocation.

You can tell from your `main()` method, you're supposed to be defining these two methods:

```
userNum1 = getUserNum();
avgResult = computeAvg(userNum1, userNum2);
```

So, define them. Here's what the `getUserNum()` stub would look like.

```
public static int getUserNum() {
    System.out.println("FIXME: Finish getUserNum()");
    return -1;
}
```

I'll leave `computeAvg()` up to the OP.

Comment: Im getting two errors that say "getUserNum(int, int) in MthdStubsStatistics" which are where userNum1 = getUserNum() and userNum2 = getUserNum() and also it says that it cannot find computeAvg(int, int) where avgResult = computerAvg(userNum1, userNum2)

Comment: Your first error is because `getUserNum()` doesn't take any parameters. You declared it as taking two integers. Your second error is because you didn't define the computeAvg method, which I intentionally left out of my answer.

Comment: Is there any way that you could possible explain what you're saying with example code?

Comment: That would be directly giving you the answer, I've already done half of the work by showing you what `getUserNum()` looks like. Research the topics and your error messages, you will find a solution.

Answer (score 2):

```html
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MthdStubsStatistics {
   
   public static int getUserNum() {
      System.out.println("FIXME: Finish getUserNum()");
      return -1;
   }

   
   public static int computeAvg(int a, int b) {
      System.out.println("FIXME: Finish computeAvg()");
      return -1;
   }

   public static void main(String [] args) {
      int userNum1;
      int userNum2;
      int avgResult;

      userNum1 = getUserNum();
      userNum2 = getUserNum();

      avgResult = computeAvg(userNum1, userNum2);

      System.out.println("Avg: " + avgResult);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MthdStubsStatistics {

   public static int getUserNum() {
      System.out.println("FIXME: Finish getUserNum()");
      return -1;
   }
   
   public static int computeAvg(int userNum1, int userNum2) {
      System.out.println("FIXME: Finish computeAvg()");
      return -1;
   }
   
   public static void main(String [] args) {
      int userNum1;
      int userNum2;
      int avgResult;

      userNum1 = getUserNum();
      userNum2 = getUserNum();

      avgResult = computeAvg(userNum1, userNum2);

      System.out.println("Avg: " + avgResult);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> import java.util.Scanner;
>
> public class MthdStubsStatistics {
>
> /* Your solution goes here  */
>     public static int getUserNum () {
>   System.out.println("FIXME: Finish getUserNum()");
>      return -1;
>     }
>   public static  int computeAvg(int userNum1, int userNum2){
>   int avgResult = (userNum1 + userNum2)/2;
>   System.out.println("FIXME: Finish computeAvg()");
>   return -1;
>     }
>     public static void main() {
>   int userNum1 = 0;
>   int userNum2 = 0;
>   int avgResult = 0;
>
> userNum1 = getUserNum();
>   userNum2 = getUserNum();
>
> avgResult = computeAvg(userNum1, userNum2);
>
> System.out.println("Avg: " + avgResult);
>
> return;
>     } 
>     }

Comment: You should provide an explanation and format your code to make it readable.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MthdStubsStatistics {

   // create method to call getUserNum & show prompt for FIXME:
public static int getUserNum () { 
    System.out.println("FIXME: Finish getUserNum()");
    return -1;
   }//end of getUserNum method

   //create method to call computeAve & show prompt for FIXME:
   //calc aveResults

public static int computeAvg(int userNum1, int userNum2){ 
    int avgResult = (userNum1 + userNum2)/2; 
    System.out.println("FIXME: Finish computeAvg()"); return -1;
   }//end of computeAvg method`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing this course and this is what passed the test.

public class MthdStubsStatistics {

/* Your solution goes here  */

```
public static int getUserNum() {
    System.out.println("FIXME: Finish getUserNum()");
    return 0;
```

}

```
public static int computeAvg(int userNum1, int userNum2) {
  
   System.out.println("FIXME: Finish computeAvg()");
   return -1;
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).